# Using a SELECT Query to look up a UPDATE Query on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a SELECT query to obtain a variable using mysql_fetch_assoc. This then puts the variable into an UPDATE variable to put the returned value back into the database.

If I hard code the value, or use a traditional variable and it goes in just fine, but it doesn't work when using a value previously retrieved from the database. I've tried resetting the array variable to my own text and that works.

```
$arrgateRetrivalQuery = mysql_query(**Select Query**);
    $arrGate = mysql_fetch_assoc($arrgateRetrivalQuery);
    $arrivalGateTest = $arrGate['gatetype'];
$setGateAirportSQL = "UPDATE pilots SET currentgate = '".$arrivalGateTest."' WHERE pilotid = '".$pilotid."'";
    $setGateAirportQuery = mysql_query($setGateAirportSQL);

    // Close MySQL Connection
    mysql_close($link);
```

This will just make the field to update have nothing in it, however whenever I remove the variable from the SELECT to one I define, array or not, it will work.

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really clear. Have you checked if the select returns anything at all?

Comment: Where $pilotid came from..??

Comment: $pilotid is a variable - that works fine I've tested it.
The select value returns and I've confirmed it with echoing it further in the code.

Comment: Try echo'ing a string with those variables in it. EG:
`echo "UPDATE pilots SET currentgate = '".$arrivalGateTest."' WHERE pilotid = '".$pilotid."'"`

Comment: I've tried that however and it comes back perfectly, which is extremely odd...

Comment: Are you sure your query is correct. Try echo'ing: `echo mysql_error();` after the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Is `arrivalGateTest` a number or a string? How did you try to put another value in the query? If you are sure the previous query returns a value, try to write: `$setGateAirportSQL = "UPDATE pilots SET currentgate = '$arrivalGateTest' WHERE pilotid = '$pilotid'";`.

Comment: arrivalGateTest is a string. I've tried resetting $arrGate['gatetype'] with "Test" and that works. Unfortunately your code doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sql to inlcude a subquery.

You could use the following general syntax:

```
UPDATE pilots SET currentgate = (SELECT gate FROM airport WHERE flight='NZ1') WHERE pilotid='2';
```

which is demonstrated on [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fed61/1)

This saves the extra query and more accurately describes what you are trying to achieve.

WARNING - test it carefully first!

Comment: I need to use the query that has already been executed due to it being a random figure. Have you got any other ideas?